# php+symfony 5.0.x autoload issue when extending abstract class and implementing interface simultaneously

Tags: php, symfony, autoload, psr-4, symfony5

I have a symfony 5 project.

And I faced a problem with autoloading.

I use default autoloading configuration, provided by the framework.

I have class, abstract class and interface defined in the same directory under the same namespace.

The problem is, when I describe my class like:

`class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass`

`class MyAbstractClass implements MyClassInterface`

I get autoloading error:

```
Attempted to load class "MyClass" from namespace "App\Entities".  
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

A line from logs:

```
Error thrown while running command "myproject:mycommand". Message: "Class 'App\Entities\MyClass' not found" ...
```

If I use:

`class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass`

or

`class MyClass implements MyClassInterface`

or

`class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass implements MyClassInterface`

then the error is gone - everything works fine.

The error appears only if I use

`class MyAbstractClass implements MyClassInterface`

How to resolve the issue?

I need to make that abstract class would implement an interface, so any classes that will extend the AbstractClass would be compatible with the interface.

PHP 7.4.1 (cli)

Comment: Typically your abstract class would basically operate as an interface.  But it's kind of hard to follow your question.  Consider updating it with an actual class, abstract class and interface complete with namespaces.  They can all be empty but should be testable.  I might add that the Symfony AbstractController implements an interface so I suspect you just have a typo somewhere.

Comment: no typo ... if I place `implements MyClassIntterface` in every class that extends `MyAbstractClass` - then it works. But once I place `implements MyVlassInterface` in the `class MyAbstractClass` - the error appears.

Comment: Fair enough.  I just ran a quick test with empty classes and it all worked as expected.  I even added a method to the interface, implemented it in the abstract class and it still works.  I just think it is a bit unusual in Symfony to have a directory called Entities instead of Entity.  Hence the typo remark.

Comment: 1. Symfony is flexible, so you can call it like you want. And that is not typo. 2. Entity usualy is a directory with entities that are binded with doctrine ORM. In my case these entities are not binded with doctrine ORM. I don't use it it all. 3. There is definately something strange. I do not belive in magic, but something happens wrong. I have created two total empty classes. without any inheritance/implementations. Named one Abc, named the second Test. If I write class MyClass extends Test - I get similar error. If I type class MyClass extends Abc - I get no error. brrrr.

Comment: Also I tried directly to use `require_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'MyClassInterface.php'` and it throws the fatal error, that the `MyClassInterface` is already defined... but if I remove the require_once - it says that `MyClass` not found... (`MyClass extends AbstractClass` and `AbstractClass implements MyClassInterface`)

Comment: And If I remove `implements MyClassInterface` - then it works again

Comment: I debugged this case a bit. And found out that the file with the class is included, but is missing in `get_declared_classes()`. How can it be?

Comment: Updated php to the latest v7.4.2, error still present

Comment: Yes! I found the problem. Finally! I will post an answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the order, the files are being loaded.

I found out the problem, bit I did not fix it yet.

The problem is that the autoloader includes files in the **alphabetical** order, but not in the order, the files must be included.

My actual class names are:

`AbstractEntity`

`EntityInterface`

`Ticket`

Implementation is:

`interface EntityInterface {}`

`abstract class AbstractEntity implements EntityInterface {}`

`class Ticket extends AbstractEntity {}`

The files are included in the next order (**alphabetical**):

`AbstractEntity.php`

`EntityInterface.php`

`Ticket.php`

`AbstractEntity.php` - this file declares the `AbstractEntity` class.

This class implements `EntityInterface` interface, so the `EntityInterface.php` file must be already included before `AbstractEntity.php`.

the correct order must be:

`EntityInterface.php`

`AbstractEntity.php`

`Ticket.php`

It is easy to check, by just renaming the `AbstractEntity` to `ObstractEntity`, then the alphabetical order will be:

`EntityInterface.php`

`ObstractEntity.php`

`Ticket.php`

For now it just left to fix the autoload order. But... How should it be fixed fast? Any ideas? Is it vendor autoload problem or Symfony?

AFAIK there is some kind of option in the `composer.json` which states:

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
```

**UPDATE**: 
Alright, I've created a new project - and everything works well.
It works both For `Entity` directory and for `Entities`. Versions all the same.

But once I renamed `Entites` to `Entity` in my source project - everything started to work with no errors.

So this is something strange thing.

I can only think that Symfony is not so flexible and the classes should be stored in `Entity` directory then the autolaod works well.

For now it's

`Ticket.php`

`AbstractEntity.php`

`EntityInterface.php`

In the way they require each other.

Comment: That is indeed strange.  Autoload is a php thing and it includes files in the order that they are needed.  So interfaces will be loaded before classes.  Abstract classes will be loaded before derived classes. etc.  I wonder if this is an issue with preloading which was introduced in 7.4?  Though 7.4.2 was supposed to fix the preload issues.  You might try disabling preloading if indeed you have it enabled. https://stitcher.io/blog/preloading-in-php-74